"How does this scam work" isn't really a personal finance question
... And often isn't a question with a single clear answer. There are lots of websites describing common scams and how they work. I am starting to believe the correct answer to this question is LMGTFY, and close as out of scope.
"Am I being scammed" and "how do I get out of this scam" are probably in scope, though often duplicates.

"How does this scam work" is essentially a variation of "am I being scammed". Most cases I've observed were from people genuinely trying to understand what's happening to them, and understanding how they're being taken advantage of is what helps them realizing that they are being taken advantage of. Keep in mind that these are mostly new users - sending them to Google won't be very helpful, because that's how they got here to begin with.
In many cases the answers will in fact mention that there are many different scams. We don't really know how that specific person is being scammed in that particular situation, we can only speculate. But the speculations we provide, I want to hope, help some people realize that even if they don't exactly know how they're being scammed - the more important thing is that they are.

Yeah, but answering the how is usually speculation, or a list of umpteen possible scams which could start that way. I grant that "does this sound suspicious" and "what you should and shouldn't do to protect yourself" have value, but for exactly the reasons you give I'd ideally prefer to redirect away from "how". Guessing which specific sting will come is largely opinion in these questions.
